# Camel onException behavior with Splitter

Tags: apache-camel

I have a strange behavior with the onException block.

If I set handled to false, then the SOME MESSAGE log isn't printed, but if I change the handled value to true - everything is logged. Could someone please explain what's happening? As far as I understand the log should be printed in both cases.

```
<camelContext ..>
    <onException>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>false</constant>
        </handled>
        <log message="SOME MESSAGE"/>
    </onException> 

    <route>
        <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>

        <!-- Put a list with some values as a body -->
        <to uri="bean:utils?method=setBody"/>

        <split shareUnitOfWork="true" stopOnException="true">
            <simple>${body}</simple>

            <to uri="direct:handleSplit"/>
        </split>
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:handleSplit"/>
        <throwException ref="myException"/>
    </route>   
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Camel bug to me. The Java DSL version of your code does not exhibit this strange behaviour:

```
        onException().handled(false).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "SOME MESSAGE");
        from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
                .to("bean:utils?method=setBody")
                .split()
                .body()
                .throwException(new RuntimeException());
```

The LogProcessor is called whatever the value of "handled" here.

Switch to the Java DSL or fill up a bug report.

Comment: If you run your Java DSL version with the shareUnitOfWork option, then the behavior will be the same.